# Functions that can be approximated by derivatives of test functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact interval. We know that functions in $L^p(I)$,  $(p \geq 1)$ can be $L^1$-approximated by a sequence $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq C_0^\infty(I)$ (by that I mean $C^\infty$ with compact support).

Now, what if we want to classify the functions that can be $L^1$-approximated by derivatives of such test functions, i.e. those functions that satisfy
$$
\int_I \lvert \varphi'_n -f \rvert~\mathrm{d}x \longrightarrow 0
$$
where $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq C_0^\infty(I)$. Clearly, the functions that are derivatives of elements in $H_0^1(I)$ have this property. Can we find a broader classification?

Comment: A function $\psi\in C_0^\infty(I)$ is the derivative of some $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(I)$ if and only if $\int_I \psi(x)dx=0$. This carries over to $L^1$-limits and seem to be the only extra condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will think about it.